# How to clear all the ruby and rvm installations that i have installed so far

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am very new to ruby i have installed ruby on my machine and currently the ruby version showing is 1.9.3. But when i try to install new project on rails it shows ruby 1.9.1 load error even if i have installed ruby 1.9.3. After surfing so much time in google i found that i can change the default ruby as the newly installed ruby by installing rvm, i tried to install rvm but don't know whether it installed correctly or not because after install rvm when try to enter the command rvm default 1.9.3 it shows an error

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

when i check ruby -v it shows like

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
```

can anybody help to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

`rvm implode` should remove all everything under ~/.rvm wiping out all your rubies

Answer (score 0):

First remove all rubies:

```
rvm remove all --gems
```

Then all packages:

```
rvm pkg remove
```

Finally clean all other kind of files:

```
rvm cleanup all
```